# Best method of copying full /nix/store over the network from one nixos machine to another

Tags: nixos, nix

Currently I use:

`find /nix/store/* -maxdepth 1 | xargs -L <N>  nix-copy-closure --sign --gzip --use-substitutes --to <remote machine>`

Where `N` is some reasonable number that will not make the line length too long for `xargs`.

Is there a more idiomatic method of doing this on two running machines?

edit:

Advantages of above method:

- Does not copy closures that exist on both ends. This also means you can stop a transfer and pick up where you left off other then some hash checking  overhead
- `--use-substitues` This will make the remote machine download from binary caches first and then sending machine second.  This is great in the common case of sending files from my laptop to a remove server where the remote server often has 100 times the bandwidth to nix's binary cache compared to my laptop
- `nix-copy-closure` copies over ssh so the transfer is encrypted.
- nix-copy-closure, to my limited knowledge, should not interfere with any other operations happening on the nix store.

[Online man page for `nix-copy-closure`](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-copy-closure)

Comment: For large nix stores the shell expansion `/nix/store/*` gives `-bash: /run/current-system/sw/bin/find: Argument list too long`. `find /nix/store -maxdepth 1` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Perhaps, it is a typo.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to use `nix-serve` to share packages between laptops

```
% nix-env -i nix-serve
% nix-serve -p 8080
```

more options how to share nix packages between machines described in [nix manual](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-sharing-packages)

Comment: This looks like a good option.  You can also specify a ssl key and cert on the command line.  Though the `--enable-ssl` which "Enables ssl on *all* TCP ports" is marked as experimental.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `scp`.
Below command will copy everything recursively to your remote machine:

```
scp -r /nix/store/* your_user@host_name:/path/to/store/copy
```

If you want to preserve modification times, access times, and modes from the original file, use the `-p` flag.

To optimize scp performance and increase speed use blowfish as the chiper and enable compression like this:

```
scp -c blowfish -r -C /nix/store/* your_user@host_name:/path/to/store/copy
```

Comment: I think the nix store is normal mounted as read only to discourage write access by root, at least on nixos.  I think I would have to login as root on both machines unmount and re mount the store as readable in order to use scp.  Not clear to me there can be other negative consequences from temporarily mounting and un mounting the store; I am just not familiar enough with the services on nixos to know.